# Can I Filter a private list within a class In mongoldb?

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, datastore, morphia

I am a mongo newbie and I am wondering wether this is possible instead of iterating through the whole list.

I have the follow class:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private List<PersonHistory>;

  //getters and setters...

}

public Class PersonHistory {
  private long created;
  private long finished;
}
```

Basically the list in the Person class will keep track of when the class was edited, then the person class is serialized and stored in mongo.
A user will then ask for the the list with a given date(startDate, endDate).

So, once is stored in mongo can filter the list through mongo with the giving dates, or do i have to get the list, iterate through it, return the result

Comment: We can do this using the query api provided by Mongo in java. Kindly refer the below [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/aggregation/) using the aggregation.  `AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("restaurants").aggregate(asList(
        new Document("$match", new Document("borough", "Queens").append("cuisine", "Brazilian")),
        new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$address.zipcode").append("count", new Document("$sum", 1)))));`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do you can use projection for this query:

```
MongoCursor<Document> iterator = collection.find(new Document("name", "joe"))
                                           .projection(Projections.elemMatch("history", new Document("created", 12345)))
                                           .iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  Document found = iterator.next();
  System.out.println(found);
}
```

You can modify projection to specify what fields to include or to use more complex criteria (for example "created" between this and than and "finished" greater than whatever).

The API doc for Projections is here: http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Projections.html and the overview of projection is here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection